# Arduino-like Makefile with dependencies...?

Tags: c, makefile, build, arduino, dependencies

I am currently trying to develop C libraries and project templates for the [STM8 microcontroller](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm8-8-bit-mcus.html?querycriteria=productId=SC1244) using the [SDCC OS compiler](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/). My target is a (nearly) NOOB-compatible setup similar to Arduino - but with make+shellscripts instead of an IDE (there are limits to my ambition...)

Currently I am struggling with make to auto-detect dependencies. In Arduino the user only includes the relevant headers, e.g. "#include LCD-lib", and the build mechanism automatically detects dependency and links the respective libs. No need to manually add it to an IDE or the Makefile.

I love the simplicity of that, but so far I have failed miserably in creating a respective Makefile. Basically here's what the Makefile should achieve:

1. scan the *.c files in the project root for included headers. Note that these files are located in a different lib folder
2. add all included headers and (if exist) the corresponding C-files to the build process
3. to minimize compile time and size, unused C files in the lib folder must be skipped during build

I am confident that make can do all the above - but not at my level of experience with make... :-(

Here's the folder structure I have in mind:

```
├── Library
│   ├── Base
│   │   ├── general STM8 sources and headers 
│   ├── STM8S_Discovery
│   │   └── board specific sources and headers
│   └── User
│       └── optional user library sources and headers
├── Projects
│   ├── Examples (to be filled)
│   │   └── Basic_Project
│   │       ├── compile_upload.sh  --> double-click to build and upload
│   │       ├── config.h
│   │       ├── main.c
│   │       └── Makefile           --> should detect dependencies in ./*.c and ./*.h
│   └── User_Projects (still empty)
└── Tools
    ├── programmer.py              --> for programming (already works from make)
    └── terminal.py                --> for serial terminal (already works from make)
```

I know it's a lot to ask, but a convenient Makefile is my main blocking point. Any help is highly appreciated!!! Thanks a lot in advance!

Regards,
Georg Icking-Konert

Comment: Have you considered downloading another IDE, e.g., an Eclipse-based one like Simplicity Studio, building a simple project with the structure outlined and seeing how the IDE generates the Makefiles? This would be a good starting point.

Comment: Note that in the Arduino environment, extra code generated by the user interface and/or libraries is prepended to the user `.ino` code in each compilation unit. You can do this with Makefiles too, adding an extra step to the processing. (One way to do it would be to create preprocessed source files into a build directory using the preprocessor, feeding it the separate parts for each compilation unit.) What you need to do here, is go through the entire build process by hand (and write it up), including the different option processing; then, use that as an outline to write the Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: I realize that this answer doesn't meet all of your requirements, in fact this approach still requires you to list the names of relevant Arduino Libraries that you use in your project, as well as a list of paths to directories that should be included in the project. However, this solution is the closest to your requirements that I could think of and it might still help someone else reading this question down the road.*

---

I use *Arduino* **Makefile** for this:

1. put **Makefile.master** in your main work-space directory
2. when you start a new *Arduino* project, you create it as a sub-directory in your workspace

   - create a single file with `.pde/.ino` extension containing `setup()` and `loop() methods
   - put the remaining logic into `.c/.cpp/.h/.hpp` files
3. add a *project Makefile* that sets project-refined settings in this sub-directory, e.g.:

   ```
   # Your Arduino environment.
   ARD_HOME = /usr/share/arduino
   ARD_BIN = $(ARD_HOME)/hardware/tools/avr/bin

   # Monitor Baudrate
   MON_SPEED = 4800

   # Board settings.
   BOARD = uno
   PORT = /dev/ttyACM0
   PROGRAMMER = stk500v2

   # Where to find header files and libraries.
   INC_DIRS =
   MY_LIB_DIRS =
   LIBS =
   LIB_DIRS = $(addprefix $(ARD_HOME)/libraries/, $(LIBS)) $(MY_LIB_DIRS)

   include ../Makefile.master
   ```
4. compile and run using `make all`, `make upload`, `make monitor`, etc.

Ensure that you have **picocom** installed on your *Unix/Linux* machine (or equivalent) as *console serial monitor*. On *MAC-OS*, you can use **screen** by setting the `MON_CMD` variable accordingly.

---

**Makefile.master:**

The original **Makefile.master** was written by `Alan Burlison` and modified by `Matthieu Weber`, and can be found [here](http://weber.fi.eu.org/software/arduino/Makefile.master).

I made some changes so that it fits my configuration, in particular I've added these lines of code:

```
### DEBUG Compilation ###
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    ARD_FLAGS += -DDEBUG_PROJ
    C_FLAGS += -g
    CXX_FLAGS += -g
else
    ARD_FLAGS += -DNDEBUG_PROJ
endif
```

and subsequently removed `-g` option from default `C/CXX _FLAGS` entries in **Makefile.master**. In this way *symbol information* is not added on *release* code, and only when code is compiled with `DEBUG=1` the code shielded by

```
#ifdef DEBUG_PROJ
    /* debug code here */
#endif
// or
#ifndef NDEBUG_PROJ
    /* debug code here */
#endif
```

finds its way into the binary, thus resulting smaller *release* executables.

Here you can find *my own* version of the **Makefile.master**:

```
#
# Copyright 2011 Alan Burlison, alan@bleaklow.com.  All rights reserved.
# Subsequently modified by Matthieu Weber, matthieu.weber@jyu.fi.
# Subsequently modified by Patrick Trentin, patrick.trentin.88@gmail.com
# Use is subject to license terms.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
#
#  1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
#     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
#  2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
#     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
#     and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY ALAN BURLISON "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO
# EVENT SHALL ALAN BURLISON OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
# INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA,
# OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
# NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
# EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# Makefile for building Arduino projects outside of the Arduino environment
#
# This makefile should be included into a per-project Makefile of the following
# form:
#
# ----------
# BOARD = mega
# PORT = /dev/term/0
# INC_DIRS = ../common
# LIB_DIRS = ../libraries/Task ../../libraries/VirtualWire
# include ../../Makefile.master
# ----------
#
# Where:
#   BOARD    : Arduino board type, from $(ARD_HOME)/hardware/boards.txt
#   PORT     : USB port
#   INC_DIRS : List pf directories containing header files
#   LIB_DIRS : List of directories containing library source
#
# Before using this Makefile you can adjust the following macros to suit
# your environment, either by editing this file directly or by defining them in
# the Makefile that includes this one, in which case they will override the
# definitions below:
#   ARD_REV      : arduino software revision, e.g. 0017, 0018
#   ARD_HOME     : installation directory of the Arduino software.
#   ARD_BIN      : location of compiler binaries
#   AVRDUDE      : location of avrdude executable
#   AVRDUDE_CONF : location of avrdude configuration file
#   PROGRAMMER   : avrdude programmer type
#   MON_TERM     : terminal command for serial monitor
#   MON_CMD      : serial monitor command
#   MON_SPEED    : serial monitor speed
#

# Global configuration.
ARD_REV ?= 100
ARD_HOME ?= /usr/local/arduino
ARD_BIN ?= /usr/bin
AVRDUDE ?= $(ARD_HOME)/hardware/tools/avrdude
AVRDUDE_CONF ?= $(ARD_HOME)/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf
MON_TERM ?= xterm
MON_SPEED ?= 57600
MON_CMD ?= picocom
PORT ?= $(HOME)/dev/arduino
BOARD ?= atmega328

### Nothing below here should require editing. ###

# Check for the required definitions.

ifndef BOARD
    $(error $$(BOARD) not defined)
endif
ifndef PORT
    $(error $$(PORT) not defined)
endif

# Version-specific settings
ARD_BOARDS = $(ARD_HOME)/hardware/arduino/boards.txt
ARD_SRC_DIR = $(ARD_HOME)/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino
ARD_MAIN = $(ARD_SRC_DIR)/main.cpp

# Standard macros.
SKETCH = $(notdir $(CURDIR))
BUILD_DIR = build
VPATH = $(LIB_DIRS)

# Macros derived from boards.txt
MCU := $(shell sed -n 's/$(BOARD)\.build\.mcu=\(.*\)/\1/p' < $(ARD_BOARDS))
F_CPU := $(shell sed -n 's/$(BOARD)\.build\.f_cpu=\(.*\)/\1/p' < $(ARD_BOARDS))
UPLOAD_SPEED := \
    $(shell sed -n 's/$(BOARD)\.upload\.speed=\(.*\)/\1/p' < $(ARD_BOARDS))
PROGRAMMER := \
    $(shell sed -n 's/$(BOARD)\.upload\.protocol=\(.*\)/\1/p' < $(ARD_BOARDS))
ARD_VAR := \
    $(shell sed -n 's/$(BOARD)\.build\.variant=\(.*\)/\1/p' < $(ARD_BOARDS))

# More Version-specific settings
ARD_VAR_DIR = $(ARD_HOME)/hardware/arduino/variants/$(ARD_VAR)

# Build tools.
CC = $(ARD_BIN)/avr-gcc
CXX = $(ARD_BIN)/avr-g++
CXXFILT = $(ARD_BIN)/avr-c++filt
OBJCOPY = $(ARD_BIN)/avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(ARD_BIN)/avr-objdump
AR = $(ARD_BIN)/avr-ar
SIZE = $(ARD_BIN)/avr-size
NM = $(ARD_BIN)/avr-nm
MKDIR = mkdir -p
RM = rm -rf
MV = mv -f
LN = ln -f

# Compiler flags.
INC_FLAGS = \
    $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS)) $(addprefix -I,$(LIB_DIRS)) -I$(ARD_SRC_DIR) -I$(ARD_VAR_DIR)
ARD_FLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU) -DARDUINO=$(ARD_REV)
C_CXX_FLAGS = \
    -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wno-unused-parameter \
    -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wa,-adhlns=$(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst
C_FLAGS = \
    $(C_CXX_FLAGS) -std=gnu99 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-old-style-declaration
CXX_FLAGS = $(C_CXX_FLAGS)

### DEBUG Compilation ###
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    ARD_FLAGS += -DDEBUG_PROJ
    C_FLAGS += -g
    CXX_FLAGS += -g
else
    ARD_FLAGS += -DNDEBUG_PROJ
endif

# Optimiser flags.
#     optimise for size, unsigned by default, pack data.
#     separate sections, drop unused ones, shorten branches, jumps.
#     don't inline, vectorise loops. no exceptions.
#     no os preamble, use function calls in prologues.
# http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/
# http://www.tty1.net/blog/2008-04-29-avr-gcc-optimisations_en.html
OPT_FLAGS = \
     -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums \
    -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections,--relax \
    -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-tree-scev-cprop -fno-exceptions \
    -ffreestanding -mcall-prologues

# Build parameters.
IMAGE = $(BUILD_DIR)/$(SKETCH)
ARD_C_SRC = $(wildcard $(ARD_SRC_DIR)/*.c)
ARD_CXX_SRC = $(wildcard $(ARD_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
ARD_C_OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(ARD_C_SRC)))
ARD_CXX_OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(notdir $(ARD_CXX_SRC)))
ARD_LIB = arduino
ARD_AR = $(BUILD_DIR)/lib$(ARD_LIB).a
ARD_AR_OBJ = $(ARD_AR)($(ARD_C_OBJ) $(ARD_CXX_OBJ))
ARD_LD_FLAG = -l$(ARD_LIB)

# Workaround for http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34734
$(ARD_AR)(Tone.o) : CXX_FLAGS += -w

# Sketch libraries.
LIB_C_SRC = $(foreach ld,$(LIB_DIRS),$(wildcard $(ld)/*.c))
LIB_CXX_SRC = $(foreach ld,$(LIB_DIRS),$(wildcard $(ld)/*.cpp))
LIB_SRC = $(LIB_C_SRC) $(LIB_CXX_SRC)
ifneq "$(strip $(LIB_C_SRC) $(LIB_CXX_SRC))" ""
    LIB_C_OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(LIB_C_SRC)))
    LIB_CXX_OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(notdir $(LIB_CXX_SRC)))
    LIB_LIB = library
    LIB_AR = $(BUILD_DIR)/lib$(LIB_LIB).a
    LIB_AR_OBJ = $(LIB_AR)($(LIB_C_OBJ) $(LIB_CXX_OBJ))
    LIB_LD_FLAG = -l$(LIB_LIB)
endif

# Sketch PDE source.
SKT_PDE_SRC = $(wildcard *.pde *.ino)
ifneq "$(strip $(SKT_PDE_SRC))" ""
    SKT_PDE_OBJ = $(BUILD_DIR)/$(SKETCH)_pde.o
endif

# C and C++ source.
SKT_C_SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
SKT_CXX_SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
ifneq "$(strip $(SKT_C_SRC) $(SKT_CXX_SRC))" ""
    SKT_C_OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SKT_C_SRC))
    SKT_CXX_OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SKT_CXX_SRC))
    SKT_LIB = sketch
    SKT_AR = $(BUILD_DIR)/lib$(SKT_LIB).a
    SKT_AR_OBJ = $(SKT_AR)/($(SKT_C_OBJ) $(SKT_CXX_OBJ))
    SKT_LD_FLAG = -l$(SKT_LIB)
endif

# Definitions.
define run-cc
    @ $(CC) $(ARD_FLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) -M -MT '$@($%)' -MF $@_$*.dep $<
    $(CC) -c $(C_FLAGS) $(OPT_FLAGS) $(ARD_FLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) \
        $< -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$%
    @ $(AR) rc $@ $(BUILD_DIR)/$%
    @ $(RM) $(BUILD_DIR)/$%
    @ $(CXXFILT) < $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst > $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst.tmp
    @ $(MV) $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst.tmp $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst
endef

define run-cxx
    @ $(CXX) $(ARD_FLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) -M -MT '$@($%)' -MF $@_$*.dep $<
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) $(OPT_FLAGS) $(ARD_FLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) \
        $< -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$%
    @ $(AR) rc $@ $(BUILD_DIR)/$%
    @ $(RM) $(BUILD_DIR)/$%
    @ $(CXXFILT) < $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst > $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst.tmp
    @ $(MV) $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst.tmp $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.lst
endef

# Rules.
.PHONY : all clean upload monitor upload_monitor

all : $(BUILD_DIR) $(IMAGE).hex

clean :
    $(RM) $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR) :
    $(MKDIR) $@

$(SKT_PDE_OBJ) : $(SKT_PDE_SRC)
    if [ $(ARD_REV) -ge 100 ]; then \
    echo '#include "Arduino.h"' > $(BUILD_DIR)/$(SKETCH)_pde.cpp; \
    else \
    echo '#include "WProgram.h"' > $(BUILD_DIR)/$(SKETCH)_pde.cpp; \
    fi
    echo '#include "$(SKT_PDE_SRC)"' >> $(BUILD_DIR)/$(SKETCH)_pde.cpp
    $(LN) $(SKT_PDE_SRC) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(SKT_PDE_SRC)
    cd $(BUILD_DIR) && $(CXX) -c $(subst build/,,$(CXX_FLAGS)) \
        $(OPT_FLAGS) $(ARD_FLAGS) -I.. \
        $(patsubst -I..%,-I../..%,$(INC_FLAGS)) \
        $(SKETCH)_pde.cpp -o $(@F)

(%.o) : $(ARD_SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(run-cc)

(%.o) : $(ARD_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(run-cxx)

(%.o) : %.c
    $(run-cc)

(%.o) : %.cpp
    $(run-cxx)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.d : %.c
    $(run-cc-d)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.d : %.cpp
    $(run-cxx-d)

$(IMAGE).hex : $(ARD_AR_OBJ) $(LIB_AR_OBJ) $(SKT_AR_OBJ) $(SKT_PDE_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(OPT_FLAGS) $(ARD_FLAGS) -L$(BUILD_DIR) \
        $(SKT_PDE_OBJ) $(SKT_LD_FLAG) $(LIB_LD_FLAG) $(ARD_LD_FLAG) -lm \
        -o $(IMAGE).elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load \
        --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 $(IMAGE).elf \
        $(IMAGE).eep
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex -R .eeprom $(IMAGE).elf $(IMAGE).hex
    $(OBJDUMP) -h -S $(IMAGE).elf | $(CXXFILT) -t > $(IMAGE).lst
    $(SIZE) $(IMAGE).hex

upload : all
    - pkill -f '$(MON_CMD).*$(PORT)'
    - sleep 1
    - stty -F $(PORT) hupcl
    - $(AVRDUDE) -V -C$(AVRDUDE_CONF) -p$(MCU) -c$(PROGRAMMER) -P$(PORT) \
        -b$(UPLOAD_SPEED) -D -Uflash:w:$(IMAGE).hex:i

monitor :
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH= LD_PRELOAD= \
        $(MON_TERM) -title '$(BOARD) $(PORT)' \
        -e '$(MON_CMD) -b $(MON_SPEED) $(PORT)' &

upload_monitor : upload monitor

-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.dep))
# vim:ft=make
```

---

**Use Example:**

Given a *dir-tree* like follows:

```
Base_Dir
├── Library
│   ├── Base
│   │   ├── general STM8 sources and headers 
│   ├── STM8S_Discovery
│   │   └── board specific sources and headers
│   └── User
│       └── optional user library sources and headers
├── Projects
│   ├── Examples (to be filled)
│   │   └── Basic_Project
│   │       ├── config.h
│   │       ├── example.ino
│   │       └── Makefile           --> should detect dependencies in ./*.c and ./*.h
...
```

You could place `Makefile.master` within `Projects`, then assuming that:

- You only need what is in `Library/Base` and `Library/User` for this project
- You need to use *LiquidCrystal* Arduino Library in your project

then you would add the following `Makefile` into `Basic Project`:

```
# Your Arduino environment.
BASE_DIR = /path/to/Base_Dir              # to edit
ARD_HOME = /usr/share/arduino             # to edit, maybe
ARD_BIN = $(ARD_HOME)/hardware/tools/avr/bin

# Monitor Baudrate
MON_SPEED = 4800

# Board settings.
BOARD = uno
PORT = /dev/ttyACM0
PROGRAMMER = stk500v2

# Where to find header files and libraries.
INC_DIRS =
MY_LIB_DIRS= $(BASE_DIR)/Library/Base $(BASE_DIR)/Library/User 
LIBS= LiquidCrystal
LIB_DIRS = $(addprefix $(ARD_HOME)/libraries/, $(LIBS)) $(MY_LIB_DIRS)

include ../../Makefile.master
```

Note that `common.h` should be automatically detected because it is located in `.`, and there should be no need to add the latter to `INC_DIRS`.

---

*Final Note:* last time I tested this configuration I was using version `1.0.5` of *Arduino* source code, and it was working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a discussion, along with a sample implementation, of an automatic dependency generation method for GNU make [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).  You don't say you're using GNU make so I'm just assuming.

I don't know if that's sufficient for you or not; it wasn't clear from your statements about your requirements.

Comment: thanks for your fast response, I'll have a look.

And yes, I am using GNU make. Sorry for not mentioning it.

I'll let you know if this fits my needs - and level of understanding...

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks a lot to all for the fast and substantial support! I should've asked much earlier...

Now back to my (no longer an) issue. I now understand that I actually asked 2 different questions:

- dependencies on headers -> solved by both Patrick's or MadScientist's proposal
- detect what library is required by e.g. analysis of calls in *main.o*, or by the *#includes* in *main.c*...?

I understand the 2nd is much more difficult to achieve from within make...!? But Patrick's Makefile makes the manual configuration very convenient. So that's ok for me :-)

[add timeslip...] Ok, having pondered some more, would the following work / make sense?

1. call e.g. a gawk or python script from within Makefile to isolate all *#included* headers from the **.c* and **.h* in the project directory
2. for each included *xyz.h* check if a corresponding *make_xyz* exists in one of the Lib directories (would be part of the Lib)
3. if yes, include that makefile for compilation in the master *Makefile*

Does that somehow make sense...? Thanks again and have a nice day, wherever you are!

Regards, Georg Icking-Konert

Comment: This space is reserved for *answers* that actually solve your problem, you should press the *[edit]* button on your question to add more information instead of creating an answer. Having said that, yes that's a viable approach and if you happen to implement point **1.** posting that code here would be a nice answer to your own question. :)

Comment: hi Patrick, 
thanks for the advice. As a newbie here I wasn't aware of this rule. Hope this one is correct now...  ;-)

Comment: hi again,

Ok, I'll try to implement above 1. as a python script, since I'm also using python for the serial terminal. Hope it won't take too long. 

Should I pass the list of required *make_xyz* via a file with a standardized name, which is statically included in the master-Makefile...?

Comment: You can have your script generate the Makefile directly, that would be the easiest

Answer (score 0):

thanks again for your support!

Following the above advice I wrote a small python script, which uses the gcc (or actually sdcc) dependency generator. The below script scans all project .c files for *#included* headers using gcc. The respective header files are then searched in the project and library folders. If a corresponding .c file exist (same path and name as header), it is added to the Makefile. This process is repeated until no more new headers are found.

The result is a Makefile which only builds modules which are *#included* modules in the project .c files - just as in the Arduino IDE. It may not be elegant but the job  :-)

Lines 95-106 in the script are compiler and project specific, and have to be adapted accordingly. Have fun and thanks again!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

'''
 automatically create a Makefile with dependencies from
 all .c files in a starting directory 
'''

# required modules
import sys
import os
import platform
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# set OS specific
OS = platform.system()
if OS == 'Windows':
  MAKE      = 'mingw32-make.exe'
else:
  MAKE      = 'make'


##################
# helper functions
##################

#########
def getchar():
  """
   python equivalent of getchar()
  """
  ch = 0
  if OS == 'Windows':
    import msvcrt as m
    ch = m.getch()
    sys.stdio.flush()
    sys.stderr.flush()
  else:
    import sys, tty, termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
  return ch
  # end getchar()


#########
def listFiles( start='.', pattern='.c' ):
  """
   return set of matching files in project folder incl. subfolders
  """
  result = set()
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start):
    for file in files:
      if file.endswith(pattern):
        #print(os.path.join(root, file))
        result.add(os.path.join(root, file))
  return result
  # end listFiles()


#########
def listSubdirs( start='.' ):
  """
   return set of subdirectories in given folder
  """
  result = set()
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start):
    for dir in dirs:
      #print(os.path.join(root, dir))
      result.add(os.path.join(root, dir))
  return result
  # end listFiles()


#########
def get_exitcode_stdout_stderr(cmd):
  """
   execute the external command and get its exitcode, stdout and stderr.
  """
  args = shlex.split(cmd)
  proc = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  out, err = proc.communicate()
  exitcode = proc.returncode
  return exitcode, out, err



##################
# main program
##################

# set compile search paths
ROOT_DIR = '../../../'
TOOL_DIR = ROOT_DIR + 'Tools/'
LIB_ROOT = ROOT_DIR + 'Library/'
PRJ_ROOT = '.'
OBJDIR   = 'output'
TARGET   = 'main.ihx'

# set command for creating dependencies and set search paths 
CC       = 'sdcc '
CFLAGS   = '-mstm8 --std-sdcc99 --std-c99 '
LFLAGS   = '-mstm8 -lstm8 --out-fmt-ihx '
DEPEND   = '-MM '
INCLUDE  = '-I. '
for dir in listSubdirs(PRJ_ROOT):
  INCLUDE += '-I' + dir + ' '
for dir in listSubdirs(LIB_ROOT):
  INCLUDE += '-I' + dir + ' '

# get set of .c files in project folder incl. subdirectories
source_todo = listFiles(PRJ_ROOT,".c")
source_done = set()
header_done = set()
object_done = set()


# print message
sys.stdout.write('start Makefile creation ... ')
sys.stdout.flush()


# generate generic Makefile header
Makefile = open('Makefile', 'wb')
Makefile.write('OBJDIR   = '+OBJDIR+'\n')
Makefile.write('TARGET   = '+TARGET+'\n\n')
Makefile.write('.PHONY: clean all default objects\n\n')
Makefile.write('.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET)\n\n')
Makefile.write('default: $(OBJDIR) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET)\n\n')
Makefile.write('all: default\n\n')
Makefile.write('# create output folder\n')
Makefile.write('$(OBJDIR):\n')
Makefile.write('    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)\n')
Makefile.write('    rm -fr -- -p\n\n')

# iteratively add project sources to Makefile
while (len(source_todo) > 0):

  # get next pending source and mark as done
  source = source_todo.pop()
  source_done.add(source)

  # convert Windows path to POSIX for Makefile
  if OS == 'Windows':
    source = source.replace('\\','/')

  # use compiler generate dependency list
  cmd = CC+DEPEND+CFLAGS+INCLUDE+source
  #print cmd
  exitcode, out, err = get_exitcode_stdout_stderr(cmd)
  if (exitcode != 0):
    print 'error: ' + err
    getchar()
    exit()

  # append .c file with dependency and compile instruction to Makefile
  Makefile.write('$(OBJDIR)/'+out)
  #print(out)
  Makefile.write('\t'+CC+CFLAGS+INCLUDE+'-c $< -o $@\n\n')

  # extract file list including object[0], source[1] and headers[2..N]
  out = out.replace(':', '')
  out = out.replace('\\', '')
  out = out.replace('\n', '')
  out = out.split()
  #print out

  # for all files returned by compiler...
  for next in out:

    # append object files for linker
    if next.endswith('.rel'):
      object_done.add(next)

    # if corresponding source to header exists, add to pending sources
    if next.endswith('.h'):
      if next not in header_done:           # not yet in list
        header_done.add(next)                 # add to treated headers
        if (os.path.isfile(next[:-1]+'c')):   # if corresponding .c exists, add to todo list
          source_todo.add(next[:-1]+'c')


# link project object files
Makefile.write('$(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET): ')
for next in object_done:
  Makefile.write('$(OBJDIR)/'+next+' ')
Makefile.write('\n')
Makefile.write('\t'+CC+LFLAGS)
for next in object_done:
  Makefile.write('$(OBJDIR)/'+next+' ')
Makefile.write(' -o $@\n')

# close Makefile.dep
Makefile.close()


print('done\n')
sys.stdout.write('press any key to exit')
getchar()
exit()

# END OF MODULE
```