# Just compile or just transfert byte code with arduino standard IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am working with standard arduino IDE.

I want to do 3 things and it does not seem to be available:

- First of all: i would like to use git inside arduino software. Is there a plugin or something like that because i do not want to use commande line outside IDE
- I want to compile byte code, without having a board connected via USB. I want to get an hex dump file (byte code)
- I want to transfert this byte code, even if i do not have source code (C/C++)

Do you know if this is possible with basic Arduino software ?
If no, is there another software which can do those 3 tasks ?

Edit: What i mean by "byte code" is the result of the compilation of C/C++. It is a dump of what is written on the arduino

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to *dump* the *Arduino IDE* and use [Arduino Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173716/arduino-like-makefile-with-dependencies/42180887#42180887) to *build, upload and test* your project. You can setup any *IDE* with support for *git* to use *Arduino Makefile* to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

I needed answer to these 3 questions (or similar); and I got them with the verbose mode in arduino IDE. If you check the check box for verbose on compile and upload, the IDE will print the command line it uses. You get up live information that corresponds to [BuildProcess arduino page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess).

- During a "Verify" the .hex file is written to /tmp (on Mac and Linux). The verbose mode gives you directly the name of the hex file.
- Sketches are uploaded by avrdude. You need many options, they are given by verbose mode.

I used this development mode with an arduino connected to a raspberry. If I have to modify the arduino sketch, I dont use arduino development on raspberry and I dont disconnect arduino. I modify the sketch on my laptop, I "verify", then I move hex file to raspberry and the single command on Pi is an upload with avrdude.

For your first question: I am sure there is no plugin on arduino IDE to use git inside. If there was one, it would not be very reliable. With standard arduino sketch tree, it is not obvious wich library you want to include in your git repository.

@Patrick Trentin gave you a way to find a better IDE.

I had some disappointing experience with some arduino-makefiles. I have checked some makefile on arduino.cc, they are too old and not maintained. 
I tried one like [Makefile.master](http://weber.fi.eu.org/software/arduino/Makefile.master) (that @Patrick proposed). These ones are still partially maintained (by one developper ?); yet they dont know all boards (I sometimes switch between uno, due and teensy, and even red bear lab), and they are not compatible with arduino version v1.5.0+. The tree changed for avr/core and for libraries.

I have found [sudar/Arduino-Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile)
 and installed it last week end, side by side with Qt Creator. It works, it looks complete and it has 50 contributors.

- Qt creator can not guess the meaning of makefile, sad :(
- So I skip common compile procedure and I tell it to use `make` for compilation, and `make upload` for deployment.
- Qt Creator creates configuration files in project directory, because he can not decrypt makefile. If I would want to use git inside Qt Creator, I would fill `myProject.files` file manually (not handy !).
- To get code completion and code navigation in Qt, I need to give include path in `myProject.includes` file. I have to do it manually, but it is always same directories (we can quote unused directory), moreover we dont need to give file names, Qt can find cpp files by itself.

There is a more simple solution to have code completion and navigation (what is not your primary question).

- I still compiled with arduino IDE, which handle all boards finely and is maintained.
- And I use good IDE (Qt ...) for code editing only. The IDE needs only all the include paths, and I can use always the same projects as I can quote more directories than the ones are used actually.